# Oracle: How do I determine the NEW name of an object in an "AFTER ALTER" trigger?

Tags: oracle, triggers, rename

Suppose I have an `AFTER ALTER` trigger on my Oracle database and I rename some database object (`ALTER ... RENAME TO ...`). Within the trigger, how do I determine the **new** name of the database object? It seems that the `ORA_DICT_OBJ_OWNER`, `ORA_DICT_OBJ_NAME` and `ORA_DICT_OBJ_TYPE` functions all return the **old** values of the database object.

For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ADAM_BEFORE_AFTER BEFORE ALTER ON DATABASE
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Before alter: ' || ora_dict_obj_owner || '.' || ora_dict_obj_name || ' (' || ora_dict_obj_type || ')');
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ADAM_AFTER_ALTER AFTER ALTER ON DATABASE
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('After alter: ' || ora_dict_obj_owner || '.' || ora_dict_obj_name || ' (' || ora_dict_obj_type || ')');
END;
```

Suppose I rename a table:

```
ALTER TABLE USELESS_TABLE9 RENAME TO USELESS_TABLE10
```

The database outputs this:

```
Before alter: DEVELOPER.USELESS_TABLE9 (TABLE)
After alter: DEVELOPER.USELESS_TABLE9 (TABLE)
```

**Update:** Unfortunately, the output I presented above was incorrect. The output was actually being generated by a `BEFORE DDL` trigger and an `AFTER DDL` trigger I had created earlier, **not** by the `BEFORE RENAME` and `AFTER RENAME` triggers. I will continue to investigate why the `BEFORE RENAME` and `AFTER RENAME` triggers are not firing...

**Update:** It appears that the `BEFORE RENAME` and `AFTER RENAME` triggers refuse to fire, but the `BEFORE ALTER` and `AFTER ALTER` triggers do. I have updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ALTER RENAME` won't fire the trigger, `RENAME x TO y` will.

As for your question about names before and after, I think you will have to parse the DDL to retrieve them, like that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MK_BEFORE_RENAME BEFORE RENAME ON SCHEMA 
DECLARE 
  sql_text ora_name_list_t;
  v_stmt VARCHAR2(2000);
  n PLS_INTEGER; 
BEGIN  
  n := ora_sql_txt(sql_text);
  FOR i IN 1..n LOOP
   v_stmt := v_stmt || sql_text(i);
  END LOOP;

  Dbms_Output.Put_Line( 'Before: ' || regexp_replace( v_stmt, 'rename[[:space:]]+([a-z0-9_]+)[[:space:]]+to.*', '\1', 1, 1, 'i' ) );
  Dbms_Output.Put_Line( 'After: ' || regexp_replace( v_stmt, 'rename[[:space:]]+.*[[:space:]]+to[[:space:]]+([a-z0-9_]+)', '\1', 1, 1, 'i' ) );
END;
```

The regular expressions could surely be written more clearly, but it works:

```
RENAME 
mktestx
TO                 mktesty;

Before: mktestx
After: mktesty
```

**UPDATE** To accommodate your changed question:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MK_AFTER_ALTER AFTER ALTER ON SCHEMA 
DECLARE 
  sql_text ora_name_list_t;
  v_stmt VARCHAR2(2000);
  n PLS_INTEGER; 
BEGIN  
  n := ora_sql_txt(sql_text);
  FOR i IN 1..n LOOP
   v_stmt := v_stmt || sql_text(i);
  END LOOP;

  Dbms_Output.Put_Line( 'Before: ' || regexp_replace( v_stmt, 'alter[[:space:]]+table[[:space:]]+([a-z0-9_]+)[[:space:]]+rename[[:space:]]+to.*', '\1', 1, 1, 'i' ) );
  Dbms_Output.Put_Line( 'After: ' || regexp_replace( v_stmt, 'alter[[:space:]]+table[[:space:]]+.*to[[:space:]]+([a-z0-9_]+)', '\1', 1, 1, 'i' ) );
END;
```