# Oracle : How to Log Table Rename Event using DDL Trigger

Tags: oracle

I am using the following DDL Trigger for all DDL Event. 
But it is not going to be executed in case of the table rename.

And My DDL Statement is :

***Alter table "ABC" rename to "ABC1"***

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AUDIT_DDL_TRIGGER AFTER ddl  ON schema
DECLARE
BEGIN
    INSERT
    INTO DD_DB_OBJECT_DDL_LOG
      (
        LAST_UPD_TS,
        osuser,
        current_user,
        host,
        terminal,
        owner,
        type,
        name,
        sysevent
      )
      VALUES
      (
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        sys_context('USERENV','OS_USER') ,
        sys_context('USERENV','CURRENT_USER') ,
        sys_context('USERENV','HOST') ,
        sys_context('USERENV','TERMINAL') ,
        ora_dict_obj_owner,
        ora_dict_obj_type,
        ora_dict_obj_name,
        ora_sysevent
      );
 END;
```

Please Suggest me the solution.

Comment: I think you are looking for this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809787/oracle-how-do-i-determine-the-new-name-of-an-object-in-an-after-alter-trigger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used `AFTER DDL` keyword while creating trigger. User  `AFTER RENAME` keyword for triggering while rename database object.

Example

```
create or replace TRIGGER AUDIT_DDL_TRIGGER AFTER ddl or ALTER OR RENAME ON schema
      DECLARE
        sql_text ora_name_list_t;
        n        pls_integer;
        IS_ALLOWED_TBL_TYPE NUMBER(1) := 0;
        IP_PREFIX           VARCHAR(50);
        V_OLD_NAME          VARCHAR2(30);
        V_NEW_NAME          VARCHAR2(30);
        v_stmt VARCHAR(32000);
      BEGIN
       n := ora_sql_txt(sql_text);
      FOR i IN 1..n LOOP
       v_stmt := v_stmt || sql_text(i);
      END LOOP;
      V_OLD_NAME:=regexp_replace( v_stmt, 'rename[[:space:]]+([a-z0-9_]+)[[:space:]]+to.*', '\1', 1, 1, 'i' );
      V_NEW_NAME:=regexp_replace( v_stmt, 'rename[[:space:]]+.*[[:space:]]+to[[:space:]]+([a-z0-9_]+)', '\1', 1, 1, 'i' );
      Dbms_Output.Put_Line( 'Old Name: ' || V_OLD_NAME);
      Dbms_Output.Put_Line( 'New Name: ' || V_NEW_NAME);

  END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `AFTER DDL OR ALTER OR RENAME`.
Then you have to extract the new table name from alter/rename statement.
Like this way [Oracle: How do I determine the NEW name of an object in an "AFTER ALTER" trigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809787/oracle-how-do-i-determine-the-new-name-of-an-object-in-an-after-alter-trigger)

Comment: But it is not creating the New Table name log in my Log Table. It is Creating just ALTER Event of old table. And My DDL Statement is -> Alter table "ABC" rename to "ABC1"