# Can I send Email notification if a Procedure(object) is created or altered in oracle database schema

Tags: email, stored-procedures, plsql

My requirement is to send an Email notification whenever any object like procedure or table is created or altered in the database schema

Comment: You would need a DDL trigger - see https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:267415465220

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle : How to Log Table Rename Event using DDL Trigger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32580702/oracle-how-to-log-table-rename-event-using-ddl-trigger)

Answer (score 0):

You need two things:

- an [***`AFTER ddl` trigger***](http://psoug.org/reference/ddl_trigger.html) on your database
- a PL/SQL function to [***send mail via Oracle***](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/email-from-oracle-plsql)

```
create or replace TRIGGER AUDIT_DDL_TRIGGER AFTER ddl or ALTER OR RENAME ON schema
DECLARE
BEGIN
   send_mail(p_to        => 'me@mycompany.com',
             p_from      => 'admin@mycompany.com',
             p_subject   => 'DDL!',
             p_message   => 'A DDL or ALTER or RENAME occurred.',
             p_smtp_host => 'smtp.mycompany.com');
END;  
/
```

`Send_mail` function is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE send_mail (p_to        IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_from      IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_message   IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_smtp_host IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_smtp_port IN NUMBER DEFAULT 25)
AS
  l_mail_conn   UTL_SMTP.connection;
BEGIN
  l_mail_conn := UTL_SMTP.open_connection(p_smtp_host, p_smtp_port);
  UTL_SMTP.helo(l_mail_conn, p_smtp_host);
  UTL_SMTP.mail(l_mail_conn, p_from);
  UTL_SMTP.rcpt(l_mail_conn, p_to);
  UTL_SMTP.data(l_mail_conn, p_message || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.quit(l_mail_conn);
END;
/
```